# Docker-Compose Devices Not Mapped

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given that I have a docker-compose.yml with a service explicitly stating the following

Should I not then have access to that device when I run the container? I find no such device when running ls -l on /dev

but If I run it with the following configuration of docker run --device /dev/ttyUSB0 I find it within the container successfully. I assumed the docker-compose devices key did this for us?

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  influxdb:
    container_name: influxdb
    image: influxdb:latest
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: dbdata
        target: /var/lib/influxdb2
    env_file:
      - ./influx2.env
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    deploy:
        restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            max_attempts: 5
    privileged: true

  backend:
    image: golang
    depends_on:
        - influxdb
    build:
      context: ../
    links:
        - influxdb
    devices:
        - '/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0'
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: dbdata
        target: /var/lib/influxdb2

volumes:
    dbdata:
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  A code block would be a better and more readable way to present a fragment of a `docker-compose.yml` file or a terminal session.  Do you have a more complete example that illustrates the issue, including any relevant application source code and more details on how you're launching the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated the post, the general process is pretty straight forward. I'll run docker-compose up -d then go into my backend container via docker run and am not seeing access to a device that I'm mapping in my yaml file. The original question in the post remains.

Comment: `docker run` starts a new container and doesn't look at the `docker-compose.yml` file at all.  What's the exact command you're running?  (Note that the combination of `build:` and `image: golang` on the same Compose container is a little dangerous since it causes Compose to replace the local `golang:latest` image with the one you built, and that could confuse later builds; I'd remove the `image:` here.)